# Windows 10 Start *some settings are hidden

Tags: windows-10, administrator, desktop-customization, administration

I realize this is an old problem and this question has been asked before, but I'm asking it again here because the others solutions aren't working and no one else seems to have the problem with their start menu.

I can't edit any of my start menu tiles (the rest of my personalisations work.

Under *Settings > Personalisations > Start* it says some settings are managed by your organisation

[image: Screenshot link here]

Comment: Did you change any start menu settings in group policy?

Comment: This is due to group policies in effect in your computer. [Personalize : Some settings are managed by your organization](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/personalize-some-settings-managed-organization/)

Comment: @Biswa it's entirely possible that I did without realising it :(

Comment: @Biswa sorry I don't have enough reputation to post images, but I've added a link to the image instead :)

Comment: Open Group Policy > User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Start Menu and Taskbar. Set "Start Layout" to "Not Configured".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the tips @Biswa and @Win32Guy, I found there answer here: [link](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-reset-local-group-policy-objects-their-default-settings-windows-10).

> ## How to reset all Group Policy objects using Local Group Policy Editor
>
> 1. Use <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> keyboard shortcut to open the Run command.
> 2. Enter `gpedit.msc` and click OK.
> 3. Browse the following path to view all the settings:
>      Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > All Settings
> 4. On the right side, make sure to sort the settings by State to view only the ones that are Enabled and Disabled.
> 5. Double-click each policy that is Enabled and Disabled and change its state to Not configured.

Comment: Please do not simply link to an answer because links tend to rot, making your answer useless. Instead, include the essential elements of the linked material in your answer.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: why do I get a second markdown? Didn't I correct the answer?

Comment: Also, I noticed a lot of people haven't configured anything in their Local/Group Policy configuration, although they still have troubles with "Some settings are hidden or managed by your organisation" Therefore, this answer will not help. Including me.

Comment: For those that don't know. No change you make will be effective if the computer is still part of an Active Directory domain, ie. still part of the company systems. At least that is the idea. This is to prevent the small number of users at work who insist on performing id10t errors. First check `right click on 'this pc' -> properties`. It should say in the `Computer name, domain and workgroup settings` section that the computer is a member of a workgroup, not a domain if the computer is not owned by the company.

Comment: These polices are not coming from the local machine but from an upstream policy.  Resting will not resolve their issue.

Answer (score 0):

This message is caused by a group policy that your machine is being effected by.

Run the "**R**esultant **S**et **o**f **P**olices" command

```
rsop.msc
```

[image]

The "**Source GPO**" will show you which policy GPO/Local that is **Being managed by your organization**

[image]

Running the "**G**roup **P**olicy **Result** /**R**eport" is also a useful for seeing why/how a policy is affecting a workstation.

```
GPRESULT.EXE /R
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've just been struggling with this problem for hours.

When I would view the source it was always "Mobile Device Management"

I have no idea why, but I followed the instructions from here

https://www.xtremerain.com/some-settings-are-managed-by-your-organization/

and a minute or two later, the restrictions around windows update disappeared. The key was the following

1. Run gpedit.msc as Administrator.
2. Then, Navigate to Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Data Collection and Preview Builds.
3. Find Allow Telemetry and double click on it.
   Now, Change its setting to Enabled and change the drop down menu entry to 3-Full.
   Some Settings are Managed by Your Organization fixing from Allow Telemetry
   Click on Apply and OK.
4. Again open the file and change setting like before. That means change Enabled to Not Configured.
   Now check and see the problem has gone.